# SOS optimization; how to determine which constraints are empty?

Tags: drake

I am using SOS optimization to solve an adaptive control problem using the inverse Lyapunov method. I have been successful in obtaining the Lyapunov function and region of attraction level-set for some simple problems. Now, I am trying to determine the Lyapunov for a new system. I am getting the error "Constraint ### is empty.", where ### is a number that changes randomly. How do I debug which constraint is empty? My constraints look like the following:

```
prog.AddSosConstraint( V-l1 )
prog.AddSosConstraint( -((beta-h)*p1 + V-1) )
prog.AddSosConstraint( -(l2+Vdot) + p2*(V-1))
```

p1 and p2 have the decision variables. V, l1, and l2, are functions for the indeterminants only.
I am following the iterative procedure in [1] to solve for the Lyapunov function and region of attraction level-set.

[1] F. Meng, D. Wang, P. Yang, G. Xie and F. Guo, "Application of Sum-of-Squares Method in Estimation of Region of Attraction for Nonlinear Polynomial Systems," in IEEE Access, vol. 8, pp. 14234-14243, 2020, doi: 10.1109/ACCESS.2020.2966566.

Comment: Does the error occur during AddConstraint() or during Solve()?  Can you post the exact error message in full?  What version of Drake are you using?

Comment: What is the degree of the polynomial V and l1? When you call prog.AddSosConstraint(V - l1), it returns the Gram matrix and the monomial basis. What is the size of the Gram matrix and the monomial basis?

Comment: The error occurs at Solve(). The error message is the following "RuntimeError: CsdpSolver: the CSDP library exited via a fatal exception"
"Constraint 343 is empty." The degree of l1 and V is second-order, in particular, l1=x.T@x, and V = x.T@P@x + (TH-th).T@Gamma@(TH-th), and Vdot = x.T@P@f + x.T@P@g@Klqr@x + x.T@P@g@z@TH, where TH and know parameters, th and x are indeterminants, P, Gamma, and Psi are pd matrices, f and g are the dynamics of the system, and z is the expression I want to find via SOS. In the first iteration of the procedure, z is set to an initial value, in this case [1,1].

Comment: I am using Drake version 1.2.0. The sizes of the Gram matrix for the three constraints are (8,8), (36,36), and (37,37), respectively. The order of the monomial basis is 2. Note, that I am removing the constant value from the monomial basis.

Comment: p1, Q_p1 = prog.NewSosPolynomial(sym.MonomialBasis(X, p_order)[0:-1])
    p1 = p1.ToExpression()

Comment: Is it OK if you could paste the whole code so that I can reproduce it on my end? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The problem here seems to be that when Drake passes the program along to the [CSDP library](https://github.com/coin-or/Csdp/wiki) to solve, CDSP rejects the program as malformed.  Ideally, we would like Drake to detect this and report back to you, without handing it over to CSDP to fail.

It's possible that this is a similar bug to [#16732](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/16732).

It's possible that the [debug_mathematical_program](https://deepnote.com/workspace/Drake-0b3b2c53-a7ad-441b-80f8-bf8350752305/project/Tutorials-2b4fc509-aef2-417d-a40d-6071dfed9199/%2Fdebug_mathematical_program.ipynb) tutorial would offer some tips for debugging.  In particular, the "print a summary" might let you see anything suspicious (likely), or "naming your constraints" might also help (though probably not).

In any case, if you are able to provide sample code that reproduces the error, then we will able to offer better advice.